# How to use higher version of sqlite3 in mac

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, sqlite3-python

I got this error `"RuntimeError: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0."`
To check the version, I tried
`sqlite3 --version`
and I got
`3.33.0 2020-08-14 13:23:32 fca8dc8b578f215a969cd899336378966156154710873e68b3d9ac5881b0alt2`
So I go to :https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
and download `Precompiled Binaries for Mac OS X (x86)` which seems to be version `3.43`

But I don't know how to use it instead of the old version.

I have tried to follow:
https://gist.github.com/defulmere/8b9695e415a44271061cc8e272f3c300
to do these 2

I executed following steps to resolve this error:

Inside my python3.10.8's virtual environment i.e. venv3.10, installed pysqlite3-binary using command: `pip install pysqlite3-binary`

Added these 3 lines in `venv3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py` at the beginning:

```
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

but I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite3-binary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysqlite3-binary
```

I also try to add the lines to the code
[image]
but got error as well:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite3'

What I am doing wrongly and how to fix it please?

Comment: Sqlite3 is built into Python, so the first step would be to check if your Python version is out of date by running `import sqlite3; sqlite3.sqlite_version` in a Python REPL and if that's too old of a version, update Python to 3.11 instead. On the current 3.11.5 that command shows us that it comes with sqlite3 v3.42.0, which should work just fine. And shame on ChromaDB for not just having a minimum python version requirement as part of its package definition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by:

```
brew install python
```

it will install the latest version of python (3.11)
then install everything again using this python version by:

```
python3.11 -m pip install ...
```

and also run everything using this python version by:

```
python3.11 file.py
```